# How to get difference between two array of object with different property comparer?

Tags: javascript

I have these two arrays:

***main:***

```
[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]
```

***filtered:***

```
[
   { id: "80", link_id: "1"},
   { id: "50", link_id: null},
   { id: "67", link_id: "3"}
]
```

I need to get the items of `main` which have as id those contained in `filtered` with the property: `link_id`, I tried with:

```
main.filter(x => filtered.includes(x.id));
```

the problem is that this will return null, and also this doesn't allow me to check if `link_id` is null

```js
var main = [{
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      id: "2"
    },
    {
      id: "3"
    }
  ],
  filtered = [{
      id: "80",
      link_id: "1"
    },
    {
      id: "50",
      link_id: null
    },
    {
      id: "67",
      link_id: "3"
    }
  ],
  result = main.filter(x =>
    filtered.includes(x.id)
  );

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method

```js
var main = [
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]


var filtered = [
   { id: "80", link_id: "1"},
   { id: "50", link_id: null},
   { id: "67", link_id: "3"}
]


console.log(main.filter(x => filtered.some(item => item.link_id === x.id) ));
```

Comment: @Deep the method `some` will handle the null values?

Comment: @sfarzoso To handle the null value replace `item.link_id === x.id` by `(item.link_id === x.id && x.id !== null)`

Comment: @sfarzoso do you have null values in your main array as well ?  if yes then as suggested above by R3tep should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

you are close, basically you need to check in each item of the `filtered` array.
`includes` is more for a plain object as the [documentation states.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

check the snippet below, you can use `findIndex`, `find` or `some` to get if the element exist on the filtered array.

```js
const main = [{
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "3"
  }
]
const filtered = [{
    id: "80",
    link_id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "50",
    link_id: null
  },
  {
    id: "67",
    link_id: "3"
  }
]

const resultFindIndex = main.filter(item => -1 !== filtered.findIndex(filteredItem => item.id === filteredItem.link_id))

const resultFind = main.filter(item => filtered.find(filteredItem => item.id === filteredItem.link_id))

const resultSome = main.filter(item => filtered.some(filteredItem => item.id === filteredItem.link_id))

console.log(resultFindIndex)
console.log(resultFind)
console.log(resultSome)
```